# saving the javascript in a separate js file of single file component in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I was working in vue.js and the component script section has got really big now. I want to store the whole script externally, I believe that should be possible,

if I do `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/projects.js"></script>`
I get error `js/projects.js` module cannot be located when js folder is located at the same level as `Projects.vue` is.

so I have

```
components/
         Publish/
               js/
                  projects.js
               Projects.vue
```

what am I forgetting somehitng or doing it completely wrong...

Do I have to have components/Publish/js file included in some path that `webpack` is aware to make js file import working ?

Comment: is this a typo? ```srtc="js/projects.js"``` should be ```src="js/projects.js"```

Comment: thats just a typo here in post I have fixed it...

Comment: Can't see why it wouldn't work. Though you may have to use a relative path eg. ```src="./js/projects.js"```

Comment: When I try to put `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/projects.js"></script>`  into .vue <template> section, I get an error : `Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed. `  I think if you want to use separate js, you should import it in .vue <script> section.

Comment: yea I tried that too but got the same error , `js/projects.js` file moduile not found even when it is there..

Comment: Oh, you want to replace .vue file's <script> section to a script with  `src="js/project.js"`?!  It works when I try `src="./js/projects.js"`  or `src="@/components/Publish/js/projects.js"`. By the way @ is defined in webpack.base.conf.js  as an alias to "src" directory.